# Unknown Language in android studio UI

Tags: android

As you can see... the language on the User interface is very different. I wanna know how to change the language back to English.( I've tried uninstalling completely..removing all files from app data, documents, basically everywhere..still i am missing something).This happened after upgrading my windows to the latest version that is, the anniversary update.Does this problem have something to do with the update? 
Any and all help is welcome.

[Unknown Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwgzR.jpg)